# Etymological meaning of "mandir"

Tags: temple, etymology

Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_temple) states that mandir is a sanskrit word.

What is the etymological meaning of ***mandir***?

Comment: Do you want etymology of word or just meaning of word? Please clarify.

Comment: Yes, i'm looking for etymological meaning.

Comment: Mandir is a sanskrit word as well as a hindi word both which mean accurately mean holy place(Place of god), basically used for temple. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before I begin, I would like to mention that the study of etymology or [Nirukta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirukta), one of the six [Vedanga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanga), can provide beautiful insights into the practice of *Hinduism*. As you read further, this will be showcased.

This seemed like a simple question at first. Although, I needed to a lot of research to get the etymology of it. There are two aspects of the question that I cover: *Word roots both in and out of sync with Hinduism, Timeline of word usage and Hinduism.*

### **Word roots**

There are two main viewpoints on the word root that I have come across.

*A faulty interpretation by Monier Williams:*

*Monier Williams* in his [A Sanskrit-English Dictionary, etymologically and philologically arranged](https://archive.org/details/1872sanskriten00moniuoft) says that the word *mandira* according to some is said to be from the verb root *mand*.

Each word in Sanskrit language can have multiple meanings. The verb *mand* means - to become drunk or inebriated, *to be glad, to rejoice, to exhilarate, to be praised, to be celebrated, to praise*, to sleep, to languish, be languid, to move slowly, tarry, loiter, hesitate, stand still, pause, *to be beautiful, to shine*.

The current context context in which the noun *manda* is used in Hindi is to refer to a mentally slow person. In my opinion, Western scholars show a biased lens towards such interpretations, sometimes due to a lack of understanding of the culture as they are an outsider and sometimes due to faulty intentions. To subscribe the meaning of the word *mandira* to the word *manda* which has a lot of negative interpretations makes no sense. (Although, it has a lot more positive interpretations too).

*An interpretation in sync with Hinduism:*

Sadly, there are not many Indian Sanskrit scholars whose etymological work is famous (atleast, not in my notice). The second interpretation comes from *Krishna G. Rampa*l in his book [Sacred Structures: Artistic Renditions of Hindu Temples in Malaysia and Singapore](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=J4FGDtbgHB0C&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=Sacred%20Structures:%20Artistic%20Renditions%20of%20Hindu%20Temples%20in%20Malaysia%20and%20Singapore&source=bl&ots=On7zMlALOC&sig=vx43KtOgsA7SQBeAKx8jNZzFS5Y&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNvOPSr7LMAhWMHo4KHWkbDMIQ6AEINDAG). He writes:

> **The word *mandira* is derived from the words *man* which symbolises inner-self and *dir* which means a dwelling place. In several *Hindu*
>   texts, the Lord is described as one's "inner-self". A *Hindu* temple
>   can be a separate structure or part of a building. Most practising
>   *Hindus* maintain an altar at their homes for daily worship and
>   meditation.**
>
> This interpretation makes much more sense. I would like to add to
>   this. The word *mandira* can be seen to originate from the words *manas*
>   and *dhiraya*. The word *manas* means -  imagination, intention, mind,
>   spirit, mood, perception, intelligence, desire, thought. The verb
>   *dhiraya* means -  gets comfort, is encouraged. *dhiraya* in Sanskrit can be seen as the root of *dira* in Hindi . ***Hence, mandira
>   means a place where the mind gets comfort, intelligence and
>   imagination is encouraged.***

The above meaning have been taken from [Samskrita Sabdartha Kaustubha – A Sanskrit-Hindi Dictionary](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi0u5bBtLLMAhWDCY4KHQPsBpcQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sanskritebooks.org%2F2010%2F11%2Fsamskrita-sabdartha-kaustubha-sanskrit-hindi-dictionary-dp-chaturvedi-1928%2F&usg=AFQjCNG5yHgBQnzOXgCRwqEVwF-YDTcLUQ&sig2=ETK9ejTBRFWAfrPC3wf2jA&bvm=bv.120853415,d.c2E) by *Dwarikaprasad Chaturvedi*. (I have translated the Hindi words to English for the convenience of the readers).

### **Timeline of word usage and Hinduism**

[image: Usage of the word Mandir over time]

The top chart in the image shows the [mention](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=mandir&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmandir%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMandir%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmandir%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMANDIR%3B%2Cc0) of the word *mandir* in the *books indexed by Google* till now. The bottom chart shows the [recorded usage](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/mandir) of the word *mandir* by the *Collins-Dictionary*.

> The common feature in both the charts is that they peak at the year
>   *1877*. If we look at the Indian history, the first mutiny against the British was in *1857*. **It is said that after that the Brahmins tried
>   to unite the Hindus against the British. This can be seen in
>   correlation to the peak of the usage of the word *mandir***.

Although, the later parts of the Collins chart still shows low usage of the word, which might be due to their definition of usage.

I hope this helps in answering your question. :)

Comment: I would like to add here that I recently found that there might be Indian authors who also refer Mand as the root. Although, this might indicate that some of the meanings of Mand mentioned by Monier Williams are wrong. I will add it if I find the whole reference.

Answer (score 2):

In Sanskrit, the liturgical language of Hinduism, the word mandir means "house".
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_temple

Edit: According to Sanskrit-English Dictionary by Monier-Williams "a habitation, dwelling house, palace; a temple, pagoda; an apartment; a town; a camp; any abode or dwelling"

Source: https://books.google.co.in/books?id=_3NWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA746&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=mandira&f=false

Comment: OP asked question after seeing that wiki page and you cited the same as reference. i think OP wants etymology of word "Mandir".

Comment: Yes, and in the same wiki the literal meaning is also given

Comment: Do you think he missed it?

Comment: Yes, most probably because on hindi wikipedia same thing is mentioned. https://hi.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0

Comment: @kashish are you looking for something like this:http://www.memidex.com/mandir#etymology